# Pesquisar por itens que estejam em dentro de um determinado mês do ano

Tags: vba

Preciso montar uma macro pra uma planilha que estou elaborando. Tenho uma tabela com varias colunas na aba `ordem` (na coluna data tem varias datas com dia mes e ano tipo "22/02/2018), e precisava de uma macro pra, ao digitar um mes e ano ("02/2018") em uma célula na aba faturamento, seja feita a copia das linhas cuja célula de data esteja dentro deste mês.

Não preciso copiar a linha inteira, apenas determinadas colunas que vou determinar conforme as necessidades.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Seu código vai ser alguma coisa semelhante ao que está abaixo. Altere as colunas do objeto `sheets(A).cells(linha,coluna)` pelas colunas que deseja.

Observação: coloquei duas datas: uma para o primeiro dia do mês e outra para o último, para marcar o intervalo. Então você terá quer digitar duas datas em vez de um mês.

```
sub exemplo()
dim data_inicio as date, data_fim as date
dim linha as double
data_inicio = sheets("faturamento").cells(1,3).value
data_fim = sheets("faturamento").cells(1,4).value
linha_ordem= 'número da 1ª linha da tabela de ordens

do
    if sheets("ordem").cells(linha_ordem,"coluna das datas").value>=data_inicio and sheets("ordem").cells(linha_ordem,"coluna das datas")<=data_fim then
        sheets("faturamento").cells(linha_faturamento,"coluna destino").value = sheets("ordem").cells(linha_ordem, "coluna a ser copiada").value
        linha_faturamento = linha_faturamento + 1
    end if
    linha_ordem = linha_ordem + 1
loop until sheets("ordem").cells(linha_ordem,"coluna das datas").value=""
end sub
```